# Don't understand ESLint arrow error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I do not understand the error that I am seeing, nor what I should change in my ESLint configurations to fix it, after digging around for a while.

---

I have a snippet of JS code using ECMA Version 6 (ES6) as follows:

```
const launchApp = async () => {
  await sequelize.sync()
  app.listen(config.port)
  console.log(`Server started on port ${config.port}.`)    
}
```

---

At the `=>` above is an eslint error that says:

```
[eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token => (22, 28)
```

---

I do not understand why this is considered an unexpected token.  Other ES6 styling is working OK.  I am setting the config within the `package.json` file, and the ESLint related part looks like this:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6
    },
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "es6": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "semi": ["error", "always"]
    }
  }
```

---

What have I done wrong?  What further configurations must I add?  I looked at [arrow-parens](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens) and [arrow-body-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style).  As far as I can tell, they are both telling me that the `es6` flag should be sufficient to allow for the arrow function style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrow functions are es2015, but *async* arrow functions are es2017. Set your `"ecmaVersion"` to `2017` (or higher) and it should work. [See this finished proposals chart for when each ES feature post 2015 was added.](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md)